# Proper paint repair from bird droppings?

Tags: paint

If bird droppings were left untreated so long that paint has already been damaged (like even after washing you can still see the dropping marks/shades), what is the proper way to fix the paint?

Is it ok just to respray on top, so that it is thick enough to cover up the marks/shades?

Or is it required to scrape off the paint from that whole panel and repaint?

Answer (score 1):

I would try polishing compound and if that does not work ,try rubbing compound ( slightly larger grit). B

Comment: I agree.  It helps to put excess wet compound on the spot and let it sit wet for as long as possible.  The mineral oils seem to penetrate and condition the paint.  I have also found that after polishing with compound the spot continues to improve over the course of weeks.